# tmux in WSL with Windows Terminal: Select with mouse without holding down shift

Tags: terminal, tmux, clipboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL running in windows terminal, selection with mouse works normally.
However, within a `tmux` session, in WSL running in windows terminal, to select with mouse, <kbd>Shift</kbd> key must be held down.

How can I make the behavior consistent inside and outside `tmux`?

Tmux version: 3.0a
WSL running Ubuntu
Windows Terminal version 1.14.1963.0
Windows 11

**Side note**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for copy/paste is functional in both scenarios; and copies into windows clipboard.

Comment: Output of: `<Ctrl>b :show mouse` ? If it is on, you can disable mouse support in tmux with `<Ctrl>b :set mouse off`

Comment: Mouse is off. My concern is the "shift" key. I don't want to hold shift down to select with mouse.